# How do you cite an image taken from Amazon.com?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I need to cite an image from amazon.com, but there isn't really an author/date.

Comment: Provide as much information as you can. If possible, figure out whether the image comes directly from Amazon or from one of their suppliers.

Comment: Citing in what way?  Do you intend to use/reproduce the image, which is probably not allowed?  Or do you intend to source information to the image, in which case the image is probably not the original source anyway?  To me this seems an XY problem and you probably shouldn't be citing the image at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably not be reproducing an image from amazon.

If you are indicating that you used a particular product for research, you should contact the manufacturer. In my experience (with scientific equipment and reagents), most manufacturers are happy that you are using their product but occasionally have requirements. You would likely need to include product numbers or other specific identifiers.

If you are reproducing the image for other reasons, there are legal implications that are outside the scope of this forum.

**Caveat** if you are a student and this is for an informal school assignment, you may consider a reverse image search to find the original source of the image and cite appropriately.